# own design matrix in r

Tags: r, loops, matrix

Here is my data:

```
sub <- paste ("s", 1:6, sep = "")
mark1a <- c("A", "A", "B", "d1", "A", 2)
mark1b <- c("A", "B", "d1", 2, "d1", "A")
myd <- data.frame (sub, mark1a, mark1b)
myd 
     sub mark1a mark1b
1  s1      A      A
2  s2      A      B
3  s3      B     d1
4  s4     d1      2
5  s5      A     d1
6  s6      2      A
```

I want create a design matrix of the pair of variables (columns) - mark1a and mark1b. A design matrix will consists of  length (unique (c(mark1a, mark1b))) for each unique (c(mark1a, mark1b). then 1 or 2 based on if the particular number is present once or twice in the columns and else 0. The following is expected output (not a figure):

[image]

I could understand how this can be done:

Comment: Apropos, you may be interested in the `paste0` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
cbind(myd, t(apply(myd, 1, function(x) sapply(unique(unlist(myd[, 2:3])), function(y) sum(x==y)))))
1  s1      A      A 2 0  0 0
2  s2      A      B 1 1  0 0
3  s3      B     d1 0 1  1 0
4  s4     d1      2 0 0  1 1
5  s5      A     d1 1 0  1 0
6  s6      2      A 1 0  0 1
```

Comment: How do I know the order of levels (is it alphabetical as this is not displayed here

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure that the `mark1a` and `mark1b` columns share the same levels:

```
all.levels <- levels(myd["mark1a", "mark1b"])
levels(myd$mark1a) <- all.levels
levels(myd$mark1b) <- all.levels
```

Then you can compute the sum of two frequency tables and bind it to `myd`:

```
library(plyr)
cbind(myd, ddply(myd, "sub", function(x)table(x$mark1a) + table(x$mark1b))[,-1])
#   sub mark1a mark1b 2 A B d1
# 1  s1      A      A 0 2 0  0
# 2  s2      A      B 0 1 1  0
# 3  s3      B     d1 0 0 1  1
# 4  s4     d1      2 1 0 0  1
# 5  s5      A     d1 0 1 0  1
# 6  s6      2      A 1 1 0  0
```

Comment: Matrix addition with 'table' results. I like it.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the solution from @jmsigner is the way go to for a one-liner, but I usually get confused by those nested `apply` (and its relatives) solutions.

Here's a similar solution:

```
# Identify all the levels in `mark1a` and `mark1b`
mydLevels = unique(c(levels(myd$mark1a), levels(myd$mark1b)))
# Use these levels and an anonymous function with `lapply`
temp = data.frame(lapply(mydLevels, 
                         function(x) rowSums(myd[-1] == x)+0))
colnames(temp) = mydLevels
# This gives you the correct output, but not in the order
# that you have in your original question.
cbind(myd, temp)
#   sub mark1a mark1b 2 A B d1
# 1  s1      A      A 0 2 0  0
# 2  s2      A      B 0 1 1  0
# 3  s3      B     d1 0 0 1  1
# 4  s4     d1      2 1 0 0  1
# 5  s5      A     d1 0 1 0  1
# 6  s6      2      A 1 1 0  0
```